# Python - test a property throws exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, properties, ironpython

Given:

```
def test_to_check_exception_is_thrown(self):
    # Arrange
    c = Class()
    # Act and Assert
    self.assertRaises(NameError, c.do_something)
```

If `do_something` throws an exception the test passes.

But I have a property, and when I replace `c.do_something` with `c.name = "Name"` I get an error about my Test Module not being imported and Eclipse highlights the equals symbol.

How do I test a property throws an exception?

**Edit:**

`setattr` and `getattr` are new to me. They've certainly helped in this case, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`assertRaises` expects a callable object. You can create a function and pass it:

```
obj = Class()
def setNameTest():
    obj.name = "Name"        
self.assertRaises(NameError, setNameTest)
```

Another possibility is to use `setattr`:

```
self.assertRaises(NameError, setattr, obj, "name", "Name")
```

Your original code raises a syntax error because assignment is a statement and cannot be placed inside an expression.

Comment: Since python 2.7+ should checkout @RaphaelAhrens answer below. It is a lot more pythonic http://stackoverflow.com/a/23650764/601245

Answer (score 18):

Since Python 2.7 and 3.1 `assertRaises()` can be used as a context manager. See [here for Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) and [here for Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

So you can write your test with the `with` instruction like this:

```
def test_to_check_exception_is_thrown(self):
    c = Class()
    with self.assertRaises(NameError):
        c.name = "Name"
```

Answer (score 8):

[The second argument to `assertRaises` should be a callable](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

An assignment statement (ie. `class.name = "Name"`) is not a callable so it will not work. Use `setattr` to perform the assignment like so

```
self.assertRaises(NameError, setattr, myclass, "name", "Name")
```

Also, you can't assign to `class` since it's a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

As @interjay stated, it is expecting a callable, but you don't really need to define a named function for this. A lambda will do it:

```
self.assertRaises(SomeException, lambda: my_instance.some_property)
```

Comment: Coud you explain why this deserves a negative vote?, there might be a side effect I'm missing. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You're getting an error because it's a syntax error in Python to have an assignment inside another expression.  For example:

```
>>> print(foo = 'bar')
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     print(foo = 'bar')
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But doing it in two steps works fine:

```
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> print(foo)
bar
```

To test that a property throws an exception, use a try block:

```
try:
   object.property = 'error'
except ExpectedError:
   test_passes()
else:
   test_fails()
```